# Flutter Code format was not working properly in the vsCode

Tags: flutter

I am using the below config settings to format flutter code but that was not working

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: _email.text, password: _password.text);
                } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                    // print('Wrong password');
                  }
                } catch (err) {
                  // print(err);
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Login"))
        ]),
      ),`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KJAJ.png)

```
   "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "JEtBrainsMono Nerd Font",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off",
        // "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
```

Code need to be formatted

Answer (score 0):

you can add trailing coma, it will format on  save being `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`

```dart
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: _email.text, 
     password: _password.text,  //<<here 
     );
```